# React Three Fiber mouse Polling

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm using react three fiber, and would like to update some position when moving the mouse:

```js
const Sphere = (props) => {
  const [curPos, setCurPos] = useState<Vector3>();

  return (
    <mesh
      onPointerMove={(e: ThreeEvent<PointerEvent>) => {
        //update a position when moving mouse over object
        // console.log(e);
        setCurPos(e.point);
      }}
      position={props.position}
    >
      <sphereGeometry args={[100, 100, 100]} />
    </mesh>
  );
};
```

But I've noticed that using `onPointerMove` can cause a dip in FPS because mouse position is being updated so frequently.

Is there some way to throttle `onPointerMove` or limit the mouse polling rate for my canvas? Or generally a more performant solution?

Comment: avoid using state when working with pointer position, keep your code in useFrame and use refs to manipulate objects on the scene, the useFrame hook has a state parameter that gives you tracked mouse position to play around with